# Insert HTML Before div Only If Page Contains div id

Tags: jquery, html

I need to insert HTML before the .content div for a HTML book mark link BUT only if the page contains a div id for the anchor which is

```
<div id="#bookmark"><a name="bookmark"></a></div>
```

Here's the jQuery i wrote which doesn't work and also doesn't produce any errors.

```
if($("#bookmark").length > 0) {

 $(".content").insertBefore('<p><a href="#bookmark" class="bookmark-anchor">Jump To Section</a></p>');

 }
```

And here's the HTML

```
<div class="content">
<p>This is an example of content</p>
<h2>Sub Heading</h2>
<p>This is an example of content</p>
<h2>Sub Heading</h2>
<div id="#bookmark"><a name="bookmark"></a></div>
<p>This is an example of content</p>
</div>
```

Also, not sure whether whats best to use .insertBefore, .prepend or any other jQuery method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) method is using insert the selected element before the other with your current code it will insert `".content"` element before the target(HTML string).

To insert some HTML content before `".content"` element use  [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method.

```
$(".content").before('<p><a href="#bookmark" class="bookmark-anchor">Jump To Section</a></p>');
```

If you want to append content at the beginning of an element then use `prepend()` method.

```
$(".content").prepend('<p><a href="#bookmark" class="bookmark-anchor">Jump To Section</a></p>');
```

**FYI :** Remove the `#` from the id attribute value to avoid issues and it's only necessary with id selector.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. Maybe this part is wrong `if ($("#bookmark").length > 0) {`

Comment: @Michelle :  replace `<div id="#bookmark">` with `<div id="bookmark">`

Answer (score 1):

You have `#` on div id. No need `#` on id.Remove that and use `prepend` like below.

```js
if ($("#bookmark").length > 0) {
  $(".content").prepend('<p><a href="#bookmark" class="bookmark-anchor">Jump To Section</a></p>');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bookmark">
  <a name="bookmark"></a>
</div>
<div class='content'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` for your requirement.

```
let isLoad = setInterval(function () {
   if ($('#bookmark').length > 0) {
                $(".content").insertBefore('<p><a href="#bookmark" class="bookmark-anchor">Jump To Section</a></p>');
                   clearInterval(isLoad)
                }
   }, 500);
```